# Is there a way to get a child state's stateParams in the parent state?

Tags: angular-ui-router

Let's say I have state `accounts` with controller `accountsController` and url `/accounts`

and a child state `accounts.details` with controller `accountsDetailsController` and the url `/{accountId:[0-9]{1,4}}`

Is there a way for my `accountsController` to see the `accountId` param of the child state when accessing the url directly? So If I either refresh the url `accounts/1` or access it trough the address bar, is there a way for my accountsController to know the value of the parameter?

I need it so I can set the current account to selected and other stuff like that.